# How to print Tree parser use TreePrint mothed on form text in Java SWT (GUI)

Tags: java, swing, tree, stanford-nlp

I used method of Stanford Parser to paser a statement. But I don't know use TreePrint method to print resuilt in text form SWT . I try to search but it just print onto console.

```
private Text textDisplay;


 TreePrint treePrint = new TreePrint("penn, typedDependencies");
                  treePrint.printTree(statement);
textDisplay.setText( treePrint.printTree(statement)); // It not run treeprint is void method
```

Comment: What does this have to do with natural language processing? And do you realize that SWT & Swing are competing GUI tool-kits that do not mix? This question is very confusing. I cannot even figure out what the question is.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the String representation of a tree you should use:

```
statement.toString();
```